# Python: Generating candidate itemsets for Relative Support Apriori Algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, list, data-mining, apriori

> Please note: Title of this question might be ambiguous so I request
>   other users to please edit it. I was not able to come up with a suitable title which fits this problem.

*The problem discussed above is a part of an algorithm called RSAA (Relative Support Apriori Algorithm), here's the research paper link: http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=937663*

**Problem**: I am implementing algorithms like apriori using python, and while doing so I am facing an issue where I have generate patterns (candidate itemsets) like these at each step of the algorithm.

- At each step the length of the sublists in the main list should be
  incremented by 1.
- Output of one step is going to be the input for the next step.
- Sublists in the main list can occur in any order, and numbers inside
  sublists can occur in any order.

**Here's the example:**

**Input:**

```
input = [[5, 3], [5, 4], [5, 6], [7, 6]]
```

**Output** should be:

```
output = [[5,3,4], [5,3,6], [4,5,6], [5,6,7]]
```

*Each sublist of output list (^) must have only 3 items (example: [5,3,4]) .*

The approach to solve this problem should be **generic**, because in the **next step:**

**Input:**

```
input = [[5,3,4], [5,3,6], [4,5,6], [5,6,7]]
```

**Output:**

```
output = [[5,3,4,6], [4,5,6,7]]
```

*Each sublist of output list (^) must have only 4 items.*

*( [5,3,4,6] is formed by joining [5,3,4] and [5,3,6].
We can't join [5,3,4] and [5,6,7] because doing so would create [5,3,4,6,7] which will be of length = 5 )*

Comment: I see some requirements, but no actual code. Have you tried to solve this yourself? How are the subsequent lists related to the previous ones? If you can write that down, then you should be able to code it.

Comment: i tried solving this using itertools.combinations() but was not able to come up with a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your requirement is included in apriori.
I wrote a blog about the algorithm, but unfortunately in chinese.
Here is the link http://www.zealseeker.com/archives/apriori-algorithm-python/
Here is the [snippets](https://code.csdn.net/snippets/478706) (also hosted in chinese)

`has_infrequent_subset` and `apriori_gen` may be the two functions you want.

If the code is useful for you, comment my answer and I'll be glade to continue help you.

---

### update

It is easy to get the intersection and difference of two sequence in python.

```
a = set([5, 6])
b = set([6, 7])
c = a & b # get the itersection
if len(c) == len(a) - 1: 
  return a | b # their union
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can you give me a sample `L_last` list for which `apriori_gen(L_last)` gives a sample output, so that I can know if it will meet my requirements. I tried my input list `[[5, 3], [5, 4], [5, 6], [7, 6]]` , but it is returning an empty list.

Comment: Ok, here's the update: I didn't run function `has_infrequent_subset` and the output I am getting for `[ [5, 3], [5, 4], [5, 6], [7, 6] ]` is `[[5, 3, 4], [5, 3, 6], [5, 4, 6]]`. It is missing itemset `[5,6,7]`
Please let me know what to do.

Comment: @kshikhar I don't know whether you are reproducing apriori. In apriori, [ 5, 7 ] must be a frequent set if you want to consider [5, 6, 7]. So it is impossible that [ 5, 6, 7 ] is frequent while [ 5, 7 ] is not. If you insist on your algorithm without considering the performance, you can do it youself. For example make sure two `l-level` sets have exactly `l-1` common items

Comment: code in your updated answer works well. Though I implemented the algorithm myself which uses sets too, but your approach is more concise and crisp. Thank you.